# Facebook connect vs existing account - How to link those two?

Tags: login, signup-signon, facebook-connect

Since we have introduced FB connect to our web page, we have noticed that users became confused a lot and a significant number of users began to have multiple accounts.

After they log in somehow (via FB or casual mail login) we used to show a page that asks them to connect their accounts. It is easy when they logged in via e-mail. We simply ask them to connect with FB.

I am quite confused how to handle those logged in with FB and have an existing (e-mail) account.

Do you have any suggestions or comments?

Comment: If they're logged in used FB (presumably they don't have an associataed email at this point), is this to enable notifications/direct marketing? Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The main reason is to keep users' content and give them multiple access point to reach one profile. 

Our main need is not direct marketing, but that is one side of the medal. We have a community based webpage (and a mobile app as well) and we want login process to be as simple as possible.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986578/facebook-connect-email-address - If they have the same email addresses, merge the accounts.

Comment: Not sure why you think the linking of account login methods from email to FB could not be reversed also to FB to email?

Comment: kontur may you paraphrase your question once again? The reason connecting two accounts is to keep their content (posts, images, features etc.) from both accounts in one place.

Comment: What I mean is this: You write that you ask users logged in with their email to connect to their FB accounts, right? Why could you not to the same for users logged in with FB and ask them to connect their email-login accounts?

Comment: To clarify my problem, we have problem connecting our existing users account when they connect with FB. Here is the scenario that we have trouble:

-User has an account signed it with a mail address X
-He/She connects with his/her FB (with mail address Y) without signing in with account associated with X address.
-The next screen user sees is a sign-in like form and says "Connect your FB with your existing account." [We simply expect the user to fill this form with his/her X mail adress already in our DB]
-Or they can skip.[that is what they usually do]

Comment: There is little you can do about that - it's their choice. Also, how do you know that FB account Y is matched with X if the email addresses are different?

Comment: Surely it is their choice. But we are trying to link their accounts to keep their content and login info at one place (if there are two accounts X and Y for one people.) That that is what I mean by FB account Y and mail address X.

Comment: Does the FB Account Y's email equal X? If so, just tell them that the account will be merged and merge them - don't give them the choice. If they're not equal, and they choose to skip, then give up, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986578/facebook-connect-email-address), you can automatically merge accounts that use the same email address as their Facebook accounts.

Doing this would be the right way forward in my opinion, as it requires no change to the already existing UI. However, it might be an idea to tell those who are logged in through Facebook that they have an account that uses the same email before you merge them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is how we deal when they have same mail address. 

When a user first connected with FB, we ask user to link their account with existing (if they have one) by filling another sign in form or skip this step, which is confusing most of our users. (It is kind of weird to ask them log in once more when they are connected already.)

I want this process to be simple and understandable in the UX point of view.

Comment: Then automatically have it tell them that there's an account that uses their email address, rather than just ask if they have one. If they don't have the same mail address, then they should be treated separately.

Answer (score 0):

There are three cases

1. User logs in with FB and uses a common e-mail id on FB and your website. You should link these two and you can keep the user informed about this update. The user has already provided access to Facebook profile and I am sure no one would mind clubbing these two.
2. User logs in with FB and uses different e-mail IDs for FB and your website. 
   In this case we need to provide an alert to the user and let them know that if they do not connect their existing registered e-mail ID with FB profile then they will loose track of their previous activities on this website. In addition to this you can try to provide incentives for this action (if your website has a wallet).
3. User logs in with FB and does not have any other e-mail registered with your website. This one is a no-brainer.